# XMLGenerator python sax library: write out inline / closed tag

Tags: python, xml, sax

I write out xml by using the python XMLGenerator class from `xml.sax.saxutils`.

```
    xmlwriter = XMLGenerator(output, encoding)
    xmlwriter.startDocument()
    xmlwriter.startElement("foo", {})
    ...
    xmlwriter.endElement("foo", {})
```

Writing out tags is always done by the `startElement` and `endElement` functions. For inline tags (something like XHTML's `<br />` or `<img />`) I would want to write out the tag with end directly. Is there a way to do that with SAX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.2 or later, there's a `short_empty_elements` parameter you can pass to `XMLGenerator` ([see the Python xml.sax.utils docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator)).

For example:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import *
import sys
output = sys.stdout
encoding = 'utf-8'
xmlwriter = XMLGenerator(output, encoding, short_empty_elements=True)
xmlwriter.startDocument()
xmlwriter.startElement(name="foo", attrs={})
xmlwriter.endElement(name="foo")
```

will produce the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo/>
```